# Accessing HAR files from web page activity and request-response size data from HAR files using pure JavaScript or web APIs

Tags: javascript, har

How can I access HAR files generated from the activity of a web page in a browser tab and access the request-response size data from the HAR files using pure JavaScript or web APIs?
I referred the following source but don't know the exact way: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/#postData.

 How can I use the following line of code mentioned there?

 `var totalSize = entry.response.headersSize + entry.response.bodySize;`

Answer (score 0):

There is no Web API for that. You can, however, construct a HAR file by logging calls to `fetch()` (and XHR) in the main thread, but that would not include fetches initiated by other means (e.g. `<img>`). The way to solve that is to register a service worker and logging every `"fetch"` event instead.

If you just want to get a HAR file programmatically, you can use something like [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) and [puppeteer-har](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-har).